# WPF ResourceDictionary Key Property "Key" was not found

Tags: wpf, xaml, tags

I created a DateTimeConverter to convert my datetimes to MM/dd/yyyy format. I tried using it in my xaml file as:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:DateTimeConverter Key="DateTimeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and it caused an error saying: Property Key was not found in type DateTimeConverter.

Then after a bit of googling, I changed it to:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and it worked (note the "x:" before Key).

My "x" is defined by default as: xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

It is working now, but I don't know why. Can someone please throw some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an [x:Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value to a XAML object element is the most common way to identify a resource in a resource dictionary.

It's the syntax chosen for WPF xaml. `Key` property or attribute doesn't exist.

Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specs for more clarification.